# Creating an animation using JApplet

Tags: java, swing, animation, repaint, japplet

I am working on a Java program that uses a JApplet which makes a ball bounce up and down. I am able to paint the shape onto the JApplet and everything like that. I just can't seem to get it to move. I have looked into this and saw that I need to create a method that pauses the shape then clears it from the JApplet, changes coordinates, and then redraws the shape in the new area but for some reason it's just not working for me.

Thank you in advance for the help.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JApplet;


public class Circle extends JApplet {

int x=100;
int y=100;
int diameter=50;


public void paint(Graphics g) {

int xResize=500;
int yResize=500;

super.paint(g);
resize(xResize,yResize);
g.drawOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);   
}

public Circle (int startX, int startY,int startDiameter) {

this.x=startX;
this.y=startY;
this.diameter=startDiameter;

} 

public int getX() {
return x;
}
public void setX(int startX){
x=startX;
}
public int getY() {
return y;
}
public void setY(int startY){
y=startY;
}
public int getDiameter() {
return diameter;
}
public void setDiameter(int startDiameter){
diameter=startDiameter;


}

while (ball.getY() + ballDiameter < windowHeight) {

g.clearRect(x-1,100,20,20); 

g.fillOval(x,100,20,20); 

try 

{ 

Thread.sleep(70); 

} 

catch(Exception e) 

{ 

} 


pause.wait(0.05);

//g.clearRect(0,0,windowWidth,windowHeight);

g.clearRect(x-1,100,20,20); 

g.fillOval(x,100,20,20); 

try 

{ 

Thread.sleep(70); 

} 

catch(Exception e) 

{ 

} 

ball.setY( ball.getY()+spacer); 


}


while (ball.getY() + ballDiameter > 0) {

g.clearRect(x-1,100,20,20); 

g.fillOval(x,100,20,20); 

try 

{ 

Thread.sleep(70); 

} 

catch(Exception e) 

{ 

} 

pause.wait(0.05);
//g.clearRect(0,0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
ball.setY(ball.getY()-spacer);


}
```

**Bouncing Ball** Class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class BouncingBall extends JApplet {

public void paint(Graphics g) {

super.paint(g);

final int x = 0;
int y = 0;
final int diameter = 15;
final int spacer = 5;
int windowWidth = getWidth();
int windowHeight = getHeight();

Circle ball = new Circle(x, y, diameter);
Pause pause = new Pause();
int ballDiameter = ball.getDiameter();
int roof = getHeight();
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried? Chances are you've frozen the `EDT`. Either way why are you using Swing for this? There is plenty of libraries much better for animations and such. `JavaFX` for instance could pull this off more easily and its relatively simple to use.

Comment: Yes I will. Currently it doesn't work because I have tried a lot of things and have just been changing certain codes into comments to see how they have been affecting the code.

Comment: I'm trying to format it so I can fit it in my question. That's why it is taking a while.

Comment: Questions are most visible right after you post them, next time you might want to prepare your code before you post the question. Also questions are found by tag so prioritize the most relevant ones (e.g. "swing" instead of "init"), which I've edited btw

Comment: Yeah it's just always a nightmare to format the code.

Comment: Maybe you messed up when you formatted the code but those whiles don't seem to be inside anything?

Comment: Yeah they are from a separate class that I created. I just included them to show what I have been attempting

Comment: When do they get called exactly?

Comment: I just included that code that the while loops were called after

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, animation is the illusion of change over time.  So first, you need some way to update your values on a regular bases.

Secondly, Swing is a single threaded framework, this means that anything that blocks this thread will stop the Event Dispatching Thread from process new events, including repaint requests.

Thirdly, all interactions, changes or updates to the UI are expected to be executed from within the context of the EDT.

This means, you need some way to wait in the background (off the EDT), which can notify you when it's time to perform an update and have those updates synched back to the EDT.

`javax.swing.Timer` is a perfect candidate for this purpose.  It can wait in the background for a specified period of time; It will notify the `ActionListener` within the context of the EDT when the time period expires and it can repeat.

Start by overriding the `init`, `start` and `stop` methods of the `JApplet`

```
@Override
public void init() {
    super.init(); 
    timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void start() {
    super.start();
    timer.start();
}

@Override
public void stop() {
    timer.stop();
    super.stop(); 
}
```

Basically, this constructs a `Timer`, starts and stops it appropriately.

Next, we need to supply some logic for the animation...

As I said before, animation is the illusion of movement over time. We have the time part taken care of (more or less), now we need the movement.

The basic idea is to apply a small amount of change to the current value and provide boundary checking and finally repaint the result.

```
x += delta;
if (x < 0) {
    x = 0;
    delta *= -1;
} else if (x + diameter > getWidth()) {
    x = getWidth() - diameter;
    delta *= -1;
}
repaint();
```

Here, I've declared `delta` as instance variable within the applet and set it's value to `2`.  This logic should be added to the `actionPerformed` method of the `ActionListener` registered with the `Timer`

To get this to run, you will need to remove your constructor, as applets should must have a default/empty constructor.

You should also remove the `resize` call from the `paint` method, as this is just going to cause more repaint requests to be issued, which will eventually consume your CPU.

When you run it, you might get lucky and see the circle, occasionally (or it will flicker).  This is because top level containers in Swing aren't double buffered.  Now, you could implement your own buffering strategy, but Swing components are double buffered by default...

To fix this, we can create a simple `DrawPanel` that extends from a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method

So you could end up with something more like...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Circle extends JApplet {

    private int delta = 2;

    private Timer timer;
    private DrawPane drawPane;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        drawPane = new DrawPane();
        add(drawPane);
        timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int x = drawPane.getAnimationX();
                int diameter = drawPane.getDiameter();
                x += delta;
                if (x < 0) {
                    x = 0;
                    delta *= -1;
                } else if (x + diameter > getWidth()) {
                    x = getWidth()- diameter;
                    delta *= -1;
                }
                drawPane.setAnimationX(x);
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        timer.stop();
        super.stop();
    }

    public class DrawPane extends JPanel {

        int x = 100;
        int y = 100;
        int diameter = 50;

        public void setAnimationX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public void setAnimationY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int getAnimationX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getAnimationY() {
            return y;
        }

        public int getDiameter() {
            return diameter;
        }

        public void setDiameter(int startDiameter) {
            diameter = startDiameter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, be careful when overriding methods, the `getX` and `getY` methods have very special meanings, you could cripple your application by overrding them...

I'd also question the need to use `JApplet`, it would be better to simply start with using a `JFrame` which is significantly easier to get working properly.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful. This might be a very dumb question but why exactly did you @Override the init stop start methods? Yes and my application was flickering and I would randomly see the circle! I had no idea why it was doing that.

Comment: This is a requirement of the applet.  `start` and `stop` and called by the browser when it wants the applet to change state (ie, the user moves away from the page).  This is suppose to reduce the load on the CPU when the applet is no longer required

Comment: So this is why my applet wouldn't close at times?

Comment: That may have being cause by the resize call in your paint method and the fact that you may have being blocking the EDT

Comment: Ah I see. Say I started with the paint method which I first used to create the circle. How would I transition from that code and manipulate it to use a constructor, instance variables and  methods? Would I be able to use a constructor to carry my variables so that I can ultimately change them to create the animation affect? Sorry for the abundance of dumb questions I am just in Java 1 and this is my first coding language.

Comment: Not with an applet.  Applets are required to have an empty constructor.  You could modify the `DrawPanel` to do this though.  The `DrawPanel` already uses methods and instance variables.  A "moveTo" or "moveBy" method might be a little more useful though ;)

Comment: So that is why I was getting all these errors! I struggled for like 2 hours trying to put the instance variables in the beginning paint method into a constructor but for some reason when I tried to instantiate the class into my "bouncingball" class it would give me an error