# Loop in a JApplet animation Java

Tags: java, swing, loops, timer, japplet

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Circle extends JPanel {

    int x = 75;
    int y = 100;
    int diameter = 50;

    public void setAnimationY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getAnimationY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getDiameter() {
        return diameter;
    }

    public void setDiameter(int startDiameter) {
        diameter = startDiameter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);
    }
}


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class BouncingBall extends JApplet {

    private int speed = 5;
    private Timer timer;
    private Circle draw;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        draw = new Circle();
        add(draw);
        timer = new Timer(30, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int y = draw.getAnimationY();
                int diameter = draw.getDiameter();
                int roof = getHeight();
                y += speed;
                if (y < 0) {
                    y = 0;
                    speed *= -1;
                } else if (y + diameter > roof) {
                    y = roof - diameter;
                    speed *= -1;
                }
                draw.setAnimationY(y);
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        timer.stop();
        super.stop();
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a JApplet that contains a ball that is bouncing up and down. So far I have been able to get the ball to go up and down but now I am trying to make the ball more "life-like" so I want the height of the ball to decrease each time the ball bounces until eventually it stops.

I have attempted to do a while loop using the roof variable that I created for the getHeight() method but for some reason when I tried to use it either the ball didn't move at all or the loop had no affect on the ball.

I have also tried a for loop but I ran into the same problem that I got into with the while loop. I believe the problem is that I am not placing this for loop in the correct spot for it to work correctly.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please cite your original question on this topic, [Creating an animation using JApplet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648353/creating-an-animation-using-japplet); also, consider a [hybrid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513) applet/applicaiton.

Comment: Your roof is not your roof it's your floor. (0,0) coordinates are in top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

Little modifications to your code that can give you some trails:

```
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int y = draw.getAnimationY();
                int diameter = draw.getDiameter();
                int roof = getHeight();
                y += speed;
                //
                // Reduce the ball size at the bottom of the screen
                //
                if(y + diameter > roof) {
                    if(diameter > minDiameter) {
                        diameter -= (roof - y);                 
                    } else {
                        diameter = minDiameter;
                    }                   
                } else if (diameter < maxDiameter) {
                    diameter++;
                }
                draw.setDiameter(diameter);
                if (y < 0) {
                    y = 0;
                    speed *= -1;    
                } else if (y + diameter > roof) {
                    y = roof - diameter;
                    speed *= -1;                    
                }                   
                //  Simulates a little gravity
                speed += 0.5;
                draw.setAnimationY(y);
                repaint();
            }
```

For more realism, the best way would to find an equation that is function of the ball position and a coefficient of hardness for the ball and would give you the ball size.

Comment: Hmm I didn't even think about change the size of the ball that's pretty cool! That's a good idea! Well for some reason now the ball isn't going up and down. This is the same problem I ran into when I was trying to use the loops for the "lowering roof"

Answer (score 0):

Well let use continue with @MadProgrammer's **solution** from [your other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648353/creating-an-animation-using-japplet):

In your class of `DrawPane` we can easily define the `height`, `getAnimationHeight()` and `setAnimationHeight(int)` to control the height decrease as soon as it touches the ground. Please remember that in java *left-top* co-ordinate is `(0, 0)` and *right-bottom* co-ordinate is `(getWidth(), getHeight())`. Suppose that it starts from `height = 0`(top). Then it will start from `y = height`(top) and eventually move to the `getHeight()`(bottom) of your container. We will increase the `height`(top `y`) using `setAnimationHeight()` by adding an amount(say `30`) to current `height`(which `getAnimationHeight()` will return) .

So, this little tweak made to @MadeProgrammer's **solution** in your other question will be the following **demo**.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Circle extends JApplet {

    private int delta = 8;

    private Timer timer;
    private DrawPane drawPane;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        drawPane = new DrawPane();
        add(drawPane);
        timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

            int frameCount = 0;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int y = drawPane.getAnimationY();
                int diameter = drawPane.getDiameter();
                y += delta;
                if (y < drawPane.getAnimationHeight()) {
                    y = drawPane.getAnimationHeight();

                    delta *= -1;
                } else if (y + diameter > getHeight()) {
                    y = getHeight()- diameter;
                    delta *= -1;

                    int animationHeight =  drawPane.getAnimationHeight();
                    animationHeight = animationHeight + (getHeight() - diameter - animationHeight)/2;

                    drawPane.setAnimationHeight(animationHeight);

                    if(animationHeight + diameter + 2 >= getHeight())
                    {
                        System.out.println("true");
                        drawPane.setAnimationY(getHeight() - diameter);
                       repaint();
                        timer.stop();
                        return;
                    }


                }
                drawPane.setAnimationY(y);
               repaint();



            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        timer.stop();
        super.stop();
    }

    public class DrawPane extends JPanel {

        int x = 100;
        int y = 0;
        int diameter = 50;
        int height = 0;


        public void setAnimationX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public void setAnimationY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }



        public void setAnimationHeight(int h)
        {
            height = h;
        }

        public int getAnimationHeight()
        {
           return  height;
        }

        public int getAnimationX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getAnimationY() {
            return y;
        }

        public int getDiameter() {
            return diameter;
        }

        public void setDiameter(int startDiameter) {
            diameter = startDiameter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** As soon as it touches the *bottom finally*, you should stop the Timer to get rid of the *flickering* of the ball. This task is left as an *exercise* for you.